# How to find duplicate values in existing Array and push new Array all duplicate values in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, arrays

/*My json data.*/

$scope.fund = [
        {
            id: 1,
            fundname: 'HDFC Medium Term Opportunities-G',
            date: '12/05/2016',
            amountunits: '11120',
            price: '200'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            fundname: 'HDFC Medium Term Opportunitie-D',
            date: '12/05/2016',
            amountunits: '11120',
            price: '200'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            fundname: 'HDFC Medium Ter',
            date: '12/05/2016',
            amountunits: '11120',
            price: '200'
        },
          {
            id: 1,
            fundname: 'HDFC Medium ',
            date: '12/05/2016',
            amountunits: '11120',
            price: '200'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            fundname: 'HDFC Medium Term -G',
            date: '12/05/2016',
            amountunits: '11120',
            price: '200'
        },
    ]

/*I want to output like this.*/

$scope.newArray = [
        {
            id: 1,
            fundname: 'HDFC Medium Term Opportunities-G',
            date: '12/05/2016',
            amountunits: '11120',
            price: '200'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            fundname: 'HDFC Medium Ter',
            date: '12/05/2016',
            amountunits: '11120',
            price: '200'
        },
          {
            id: 1,
            fundname: 'HDFC Medium ',
            date: '12/05/2016',
            amountunits: '11120',
            price: '200'
        },

```
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the old fashion way: loop through the array and if the ID does not exist in an temporary array, put it there, otherwise put it in the duplicated array.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: My answer is the same as Amruth.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
    var arr = [];
    var duparr = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.fund, function(value, key){
       if(!arr.hasOwnProperty(value['id'])){
           arr.push(value);
       }else{
           duparr.push(value);
       }
    });
    angular.forEach(arr, function(value, key){
           if(duparr[0]['id'] == value['id']){
                 duparr.push(value);
            }
    });

    $scope.newArray = duparr;
    console.log($scope.newArray);
```